# Incorrect Python Matplotlib Polar Plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a polar plot using the code below

```
ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
plt.scatter(ts,rds,c=cs,
            s=[(y*100)+10 for y in ys],
            cmap='gist_rainbow') 
ax.set_yticklabels([])
for i in range(len(names)):
    ax.text(ts[i],rds[i],"{}".format(i+1),size=12)
plt.show()
```

There are 42 points, the first 7 of which are

```
# Theta Radius
1 249.25 0.39
2 66.25 0.40
3 239.09 0.71
4 31.82 1.05
5 114.02 0.54
6 189.15 0.46
7 359.00 0.05
```

However, the resulting figure/plot at the below link is incorrect

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs5zf.png

Before taking a screenshot, I mouse hovered over point 7. You can see that point 7 is plotted at 41.186 degrees and not 359 as it should be. Any idea why this is?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you just forgot to convert degrees to radiants?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is probably right. Let's see what happens when you use 359 degree as radiant: (1) 359 rag = 58 * 2 * pi + 0.858 (2) 0.858 rag = 0.858/(2pi)*360 degree = 49 degree, which is very close to the 41 degree your mouse hovers over

Comment: Yes, using math.radians works